# WPF Styled ComboBox in sattelite windows and control templates

Tags: wpf, styles

I have ComboBoxes that are styled using  a Setter with property=Template" and Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}"

I have two different Resource Dictionaries, call them R1 and R2

In R1, ComboBoxTemplate is defined and does some custom coloring.

In R2, ComboBoxTemplate is not present (R2 is for minimal bandwidth scenarios)

Now the problem: on my main form, using either R1 or R2 work.

In all windows that I open from the main form (this is a sattelite window then), only R1 controls are existing. 
If I use R2 and open a sattelite window, the styled control is simply not there.

Any clues where I can start searching?

Edit #1:

Here the first few lines of the ResourceDictionary containing the style "styComboBoxStyleError", the control-template called "ComboBoxTemplate" is defined in R1 but not in R2

```
 <ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:BABA="clr-namespace:Infor.Blending.Admin.DataService;assembly=Infor.Blending.Admin.DataService"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   x:Class="ControlEvents"
   >
   <!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. --> 
   <Style x:Key="styComboBoxStyleError" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ctErrorIcon_ControlTemplate}"/>
      <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ValidationErrorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

Edit #2:

Just to clarify: I have two "themes", call it "Full" (R1) and "Mini" (R2).

In the Full theme, the ComboBoxTemplateis defined, it does mostly coloring there.

In the Mini theme, the ComboBoxTemplate is NOT defined.

Although in the Mini theme there is no definition of ComboBoxTemplate, the combo boxes that are placed on my main form show a combo. But the combo boxes that are on satellite windows are not there.

As a workaround, I added a basic definition of ComboBoxTemplate in "Mini" and this works now. But I do not know why it fails in satellite windows without the definition...

Hope you get my point...

Comment: Post the code you tried so far..

Comment: Thats is not easy because its a complex scenario.

Comment: Architecture: the Resource Dictionaries R1 and R2 are in the same assembly (called "Design"), the main and the saltellite windows are in one Exe, all for net 4.0

Comment: How and where your changing the Template?

Comment: The question is *why* are you changing the `ControlTemplate` like that? I'm almost certain that there is a *much* simpler way to achieve what you *actually* want... please add a detailed description of what this `ControlTemplate` switching is achieving for you to the end of your question (not in a comment) and we'll see if we can find a better way to do it for you.

Comment: I added another Edit in main entry